# Ruby regex for a split every four characters not working

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to split a sizeable string every four characters. This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
big_string.split(/..../)
```

This is yielding a nil array. As far as I can see, this should be working. It even does when I plug it into an [online ruby regex test](http://rubular.com/).

Comment: Why would you split an integer using regex? How about just successively dividing by 10000 and storing the results in an array.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Try `scan` instead:

```
$ irb
>> "abcd1234beefcake".scan(/..../)
=> ["abcd", "1234", "beef", "cake"]
```

or

```
>> "abcd1234beefcake".scan(/.{4}/)
=> ["abcd", "1234", "beef", "cake"]
```

If the number of characters isn't divisible by 4, you can also grab the remaining characters:

```
>> "abcd1234beefcakexyz".scan(/.{1,4}/)
=> ["abcd", "1234", "beef", "cake", "xyz"]
```

(The `{1,4}` will greedily grab between 1 and 4 characters)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I don't know what Rubular is doing there and why - but

```
big_string.split(/..../)
```

does translate into

> split the string **at** every 4-character-sequence

which should correctly result into something like

```
["", "", "", "abc"]
```

Comment: Why are you escaping your first `.` and the `)` ? That's not valid Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops.

```
str = 'asdfasdfasdf'
c = 0
out = []
inum = 4
(str.length / inum).round.times do |s|
    out.push(str[c, round(s * inum)])
    c += inum
end
```